# Why I can't create a counter within a panHandler in React Native with useState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am stuck here for several hours. Maybe you can help me guys.

I have a react hook and a panHandler inside. Every time the panHandler is clicked I want to add 1 to the counter. But it counts only to 1, I can click it 100 times and nothing happens. Can somebody help me with that issue :)?

It seems as when the setCount is once called, I can not call it a second time.

Maybe it is too simple or I am missing something.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Animated, Dimensions, Image, PanResponder, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';


export default function Example(props) {
    // Initialize the state
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    // Create the PanResponder Element, usually React.useRef
    const _panResponder = React.useRef(
        PanResponder.create({
            // Ask to be the responder:
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                setCount(count + 1)
            },
        })
    ).current;


    return (
        <View>
            <View
            {..._panResponder.panHandlers}
            style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: "blue"}}>
            </View>
            <Text>{count}</Text>
        </View>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you facing issue then use this library [react-native-gesture-handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/)

its easy to manage state in that. View documentation [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/state)

Comment: It is not an issue with the panHandler. It is an issue with the hook state. I think changing the library will not help.